# How to describe an array close to a specific value quantitatively?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have numbers of array range from 0 to 1.  Now I want to describe these arrays by the standard that the more the number and bigger of data in the array close to 1 the array is better. According to the standard, we can identify that A1 is better than A2.

- `A1=[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.8,0.9,0.9,0.95,0.98]`
- `A2=[0,0.1,0.15,0.23,0.44,0.7,0.72,0.8,0.8,0.93]`

So I was wondering whether there is a parameter which can describe the problem quantitatively. Thanks!

Comment: The average value of the array or the third quartile value seems fine.

Comment: OK. Thanks for you kindly help. I think the third quartile value can describe this problem.

Comment: If the single array doesn't very large, calculating the probability of element is larger than 0.8, or other values, could be even more convincing.